# Getting 404 not found with MERN full-stack app deployment to Vercel

Tags: node.js, express, mern, vercel

Folder structure: [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKQDY.png)

I searched online that we need to put index.js inside api folder when deploying serverless app to vercel, so after changing that I've also made corresponding changes to my vercel.json and package.json files:

[top part of ackage.json content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vNLa.png)

What's inside my vercel.json (located right under server folder):

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds":[
        {
            "src": "./api/index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "/(.*)",
          "destination": "api/index.js"
        }
      ]
}
```

My cors things look like this:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: "https://positivity-log-frontend.vercel.app",
    methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
  }));
```

changed to have my main js file in the backend to be under api folder
changed my port to an environment variable
changed the cors url to the new url from the successfully deployed frontend

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you